# Azure Mobile App API Returns 500 on PATCH Http call

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying out the Azure Mobile App API and getting an error on making Patch calls.

GET and POST and DELETE works fine.

Here is what my url looks like:

```
PATCH http://mymobileappapi.azurewebsites.net/tables/Skill/c89027fa-edce-4d36-b42a-ecb0920ebab6
```

body:

```
{
  "name": "Leadership SDFF"
}
```

I have these as headers too (as I said other http verbs work.)

```
ZUMO-API-VERSION 2.0.0
Content-Type Application/Json
```

And I get 500 error back with this in the body:

```
{
  "error": "An item to update was not provided"
}
```

The same `id` works when I do a GET using that id...

And when I make the same call using same body with PUT i get a 404 Not found without any content in the response body.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the same problem when you PUT /tables/Skill with a body that includes both id and name?

Comment: I get 404 using PUT as mentioned in the end of the question including the id and name

Comment: feels like a bug.  I would recommend posting an issue in the relevant github repo:  .NET Server is https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server and Node.js Server is https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-node

Comment: Created an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/issues/368

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out our implementation requires the content-type header value to be lower case, i.e. `application/json` works, whereas `Application/Json` doesn't. I've updated this issue to be the placeholder for the fix. As a workaround in the meantime, make the value for the content-type header lower case.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/src/express/middleware/parseItem.js#L27

should use req.get instead of req.headers. Keep in mind that values can also include encoding, e.g. application/json; charset=utf-8

Here is link to the issue:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/issues/368